# Flutter GestureDetector onTap in certain page not working

Tags: flutter

Hi I managed to create a button that will show a tooltip and that tooltip will have a text content and a button, that button will redirect my app to my privacy policy page, the problem is when I redirect my app to that page using the button inside my tooltip.

All of my GestureDetector become disabled / not working even when I tried to do some simple task such as print().

Anyone know how to fix this ?

Here's my code:

```
ReusableTooltip(
      tooltipHeader: '',
      tooltipText: 'deviceContactClause',
      tooltipDirection: AxisDirection.down,
      tooltipChild: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        width: 45,
        height: 40,
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: SvgPicture.asset(
          'assets/logo/Information.svg',
        ),
      ),
      additionalWidget: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) =>
                  const PrivacyPolicyPage()
            ),
          );
        },
        child: Container(
          child: Text('seePrivacyPolicy',
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Gesture `behavior`

```
GestureDetector(
  behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
  onTap: () {
   
  },
),
```

Comment: it's not working , what's the behavior property for ?

Comment: or you can add gesture to container